# premake5 precompiled headers not working

Tags: premake

(this is using Premake5 alpha binary available for download on website)

I'm trying to port my existing VS solution over to using premake5.

It uses MS style precompiled headers(stdafx.h/stdafx.cpp).

When I specify this is my test project:

```
pchheader "stdafx.h"
pchsource "stdafx.cpp"
```

It does set the project to using precompiled headers, but it is not setting stdafx.cpp to generate precompiled headers(/Yc). Instead all the files in the project are trying to use(/Yu) and nobody is generating the PCH. So it does not build..

I'm guessing this does works somehow, what black magic am I missing here?

Here is my entire premake5 file for reference

```js
-- premake5.lua
solution "Cloud"
   configurations { "Debug", "Release", "Final" }
   platforms { "Win32_AVX2", "Win64_AVX2"}
   location "premake"
   
flags{"MultiProcessorCompile", "ExtraWarnings", "FatalCompileWarnings", "FatalLinkWarnings", "FloatFast"}

startproject "Cloud"
vectorextensions "AVX2"

filter { "platforms:Win32" }
 system "Windows"
 architecture "x32"
filter { "platforms:Win64" }
 system "Windows"
 architecture "x64"
 
filter "configurations:Debug"
    defines { "DEBUG" }
    flags { "Symbols" }
filter "configurations:Release"
    defines { "NDEBUG" }
 flags{"Symbols"}
    optimize "Speed"
filter "configurations:Final"
    defines { "NDEBUG" }
 flags{"LinkTimeOptimization"}
    optimize "Speed"
 
group "app"

--primary executable 
project "Cloud"
 location "../src_test/cloud"
 kind "ConsoleApp"
 language "C++"
 targetdir "..//%{cfg.buildcfg}"
 pchheader "stdafx.h"
 pchsource "stdafx.cpp"
 vpaths{
  {["src/pch/*"] = "../src_test/cloud/stdafx.*"},
  {["src/*"] = "../src_test/cloud/**.cpp"},
  {["module/*"] = "../src_test/cloud/Module*.h"},
  {["core/*"] = "../src_test/cloud/Core*.h"},
  {["headers*"] = "../src_test/cloud/*.h"},
  --{["src_c/*"] = "../src_test/cloud/**.c"}
 }
 files { "../src_test/cloud/*.h", "../src_test/cloud/*.c", "../src_test/cloud/*.cpp", "../src_test/cloud/*.hpp" }
```

One related question: how do I disable precompiled header usage on specific files within a project? Some of my files will not build if the PCH is included, so I have manually disabled them in the existing solution/projects.

Thanks!

Comment: Bleh I downloaded the premake5 source, and even it doesn't generate a valid vs2013 solution. Ran: "premake5 vs2013" on premake itself and it generates a solution that doesn't even compile..(for reasons not related to PCH).  Premake seems really buggy:/

Comment: for reference premake5 generates a solution that tries to include a file named: src\host\scripts.c, but no such file exists.  Removing it from the project, and its countless linker errors(Error 190 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _builtin_scripts etc)

Comment: Did you take the time to read the wiki : https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Building-Premake ?
You just need to do an embed to generate this `script.c` file ...

Comment: hum that did generate the missing scripts.c file, but it still doesn't compile because of many linker errors about missing lua functions(_lua_call, _lua_close etc)

Comment: the lua files are nested in the hosts directory, but not actually included in the project.  Tried the github repo instead of bitbucket(not sure which is the proper one), but same result

Comment: It builds, I just tested it from scratch. Just do this : 1) Clone the github repository (https://github.com/premake/premake-core) 2) Download Premake5 (http://premake.github.io/download.html#v5) and unzip the executable in the root premake-core folder (next to the premake5.lua file) 3) Run `premake5 embed` and `premake5 vs2013`. 4) Open the generated solution and build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because `pchsource` requires a file path (like `files`) Since your `stdafx.cpp` is not in the same directory as your script, Premake does not find it. Try using `pchsource "../src_test/cloud/stdafxcpp"` instead, it should fix the problem.

Also I see that you don't add `"../src_test/cloud/"` as an include directory, so that means that your pch header will be included using relative path, right ? If so, you'll need to update `pchheader` to reflect that. Due to the way Visual Studio works, you need to set `pchheader` as it appears in your cpp files. E.g. if in your cpp files you have `#include "../src_test/cloud/stdafx.h"` you need to use this in Premake: `pchheader "../src_test/cloud/stdafx.h"`.

And finally, to deactivate precompiled headers on certain files, you can use filters:

```
-- deactivate precompiled headers for C files
filter "files:**.c"
    flags { "NoPCH" }
```

Comment: Thanks, setting the pchsource to the relative path from premake5 fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I am changing a script from premake 4 to premake 5 and I had some troubles to deactivate pch on a specific file with :

```
filter "files:myfile.cpp"
    flags { "NoPCH" }
```

It was disabling pch on the whole project and not on a specific file. 
But it was because pchsource and pchheader were defined after the filtering.
When we flag a file with no PCH, pchsource and pchheader have to be defined first.